# Reading top level blocks from a text file in R

Tags: r, substr, curly-braces

I am working in Rwith files that contain blocks e.g.

```
block name { block contents can be anything: strings, numbers or even curly braces {} or whatever}

blockn4m3 containing numbers {
                                 Can be something junk like: 
                   ans{a{a[sf'asödfä'asdösdö'äasdö'äasdö}}}
}}
```

And then I would like to extract them into a vector so that:

```
"block name { block contents can be anything strings, numbers or even brackets {} or whatever}","blockn4m3 containing numbers {
                                 Can be something junk like: 
                   ans{a{a[sf'asödfä'asdösdö'äasdö'äasdö}}}
}}"
```

I assume regular expressions do not work, since there can be curly braces (and nested blocks) within blocks?

So I thought that maybe I just read every file character by character, and then I wrote a following function:

```
separateBlocksFromFile <- \(file) {
  input <- file %>% readLines %>% {paste(., collapse = "\n")}
  blocks <- c()
  blockNumber = 1 #We start from the first block
  netBracketValue = 0 #0, when reading a block name
  for(i in 1:nchar(input)) {
    currentCharacter = substr(input,i,i)
    
    #Did we enter a block?
    netBracketValue = netBracketValue + (currentCharacter == "{")
    
    #Write the character into its correct place.
    
    #Previous characters in the current block...
    previousCharacters <- ifelse(is.na(blocks[blockNumber]),"",blocks[blockNumber])
    #...are put before current character
    blocks[blockNumber] <- paste0(previousCharacters,currentCharacter)
    
    
    #Did we exit a block? If so, the netBracketValue becomes 0 here.
    netBracketValue = netBracketValue - (currentCharacter == "}")
    
    #Block number is updated, if needed.
    #Updated when we pass "}" character and the character ends a block i.e.
    #netBracketValue == 0
    blockNumber <- blockNumber + (netBracketValue == 0)*(currentCharacter == "}")
  }
  
  return(blocks)
}
```

While this works, the solution tends to be a bit slow when dealing with larger files. I was wondering whether there is a faster methods to accomplish this?

EDIT: The block contents cannot have closing } before opening {. If this was the case, then there would no way knowing if we exited a block for sure.

Comment: Don’t concatenate the result strings progressively, that’s probably by far the slowest part. Instead, take note of the starting position of the current block and, once you find the end of the block, extract the substring from the last start to the current end. Or, instead, take note of all start and end positions and then, at the end, call `substring()` *once* to get all substrings based on vectors of start and end positions.